# Twig render array key with a dash in it

Tags: php, twig

How do you render a value of the value of an array key when it has a dash in the name?

I have this snippet:

```
$snippet = "
    {{ one }}
    {{ four['five-six'] }}
    {{ ['two-three'] }}
";

$data = [
    'one' => 1,
    'two-three' => '2-3',
    'four' => [
        'five-six' => '5-6',
    ],
];

$twig = new \Twig_Environment(new \Twig_Loader_String());
echo $twig->render($snippet, $data);
```

The output is

```
1
5-6
Notice: Array to string conversion in path/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(320) : eval()'d code on line 34
```

And it renders `four['five-six']` fine. But throws an error on `['two-three']`.

Comment: Thats because `two-three` is being used as a local symbol.. it be like trying to use `$two-three` in raw PHP. IF you are using Twig as in your example then you should pass the array in as the member of another array with the variable name as the key like `$data = array('values' => $theOtherArray);`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This cannot work, since you shouldn't be using native operators in variable names - Twig internally compiles to PHP so it cannot handle this.

For attributes (methods or properties of a PHP object, or items of a PHP array) there is a workaround, [from the documentation:](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables)

> When the attribute contains special characters (like - that would be
>   interpreted as the minus operator), use the attribute function instead
>   to access the variable attribute:
>
> ```
> {# equivalent to the non-working foo.data-foo #}
> {{ attribute(foo, 'data-foo') }}
> ```

Comment: I guess you can use `{{ attribute(_context, 'data-foo') }}` for non-multidimentional array @ twig 2.x.

Answer (score 9):

Actually this can work, and it works:

```
        $data = [
            "list" => [
                "one" => [
                    "title" => "Hello world"
                ],
                "one-two" => [
                    "title" => "Hello world 2"
                ],
                "one-three" => [
                    "title" => "Hello world 3"
                ]
            ]
        ];
        $theme = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem("path_to_your_theme_directory");
        $twig = new Twig_Environment($theme, array("debug" => true));
        $index = "index.tmpl"; // your index template file
        echo $this->twig->render($index, $data);
```

And snippets to use inside template file:

```
{{ list["one-two"]}} - Returns: Array
{{ list["one-two"].title }} - Returns: "Hello world 2"
```

Comment: This is a different case, nested in an object. It doesn't answer the original question which still requires the workaround.

Comment: Thank you. This is good to know way of doing for dash-separated keys. Especially useful to quickly pass the numerous form data items with convenient dashed keys to email templates.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes nesting one level down - wont make much of a difference (this is the only solution I found that works for dash-keys)